# unable to connect to PostgreSQL from cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

In my feature test I use byebug to check the database connection

```
/myfeaturesteps.rb

Given(/^I have an application "(.*?)"$/) do |name|
byebug

>Rails.env
>'test'

>ActiveRecord::Base.connected?
>true
```

When I try to touch the database

```
>User.first
>ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor:
```

When I run console on test environment

```
rails console test

>Rails.env
>'test'

>User.first
User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

The same command on the same rails environment gives different results, where does the cucumber gets its connection settings ?

Comment: Your local `config/database.yml` ... does it have any special provision for cucumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it does not use a valid connection to connect to your database. This requires a lot of investigation. However, you can try a workaround. Add the following lines in order to create a `Before` hook:

```
Before do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.verify!
end
```

I believe that this will solve your problem, until you find out what is the real cause of it.